# Phonegap Barcode Scanner Negative Datamatrix Reading

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode

I have installed the Barcode Scanner plugin for phonegap from https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git and it works mostly great. However, I need it to be able to scan a datamatrix barcode that is inverted in color. The following image shows what I am referring to: http://epsfiles.intermec.com/eps_files/eps_download/scanner/KC/12852_03.gif My app scans the top barcode fine, but not the bottom. I think it is because it is inverted or negative. Can the Barcode plugin be configured to scan this type or barcode?